# how to show selected data in textbox using C#?

Tags: c#

I am new on C# language. I have to create project in C# that shows selected data from list box or combo box in text box.

Simply when i click on ADD button the selected text in listbox or combo box will be showed on textbox..

Comment: @Umair Try first and then ask help if you get stuck.Nobody will do your task.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5gyINjernc

Plenty more tutorials after a simple google search.

Comment: Try `ComboBox/ListBox.SelectedXXXXX` methods & properties.

Comment: if you tried you would have got the answer or else post your code

Answer (score 2):

-Open Visual Studio
-Create a C# Winform application
-In the form designer, drag and drop a Button, TextBox and ComboBox controls onto the form
-Double click the Form to see the Form_Load event and add this code:

```
string aBitOfText = "blindfolded coding";
combobox1.Items.Add(aBitOfText);
```

-Back to the form designer view
-Double click the Button and add this to the Button's Click Event

```
TextBox1.Text = combobox1.Text;
```

Comment: THANKS @Jeremy Thompson
It works.